# `git rebase` not updating branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I have this:

```
        master
        |   foo
        |   |
        v   v             bar
A---B---C---D             |
             \            v
              \---E---F---G
```

I want this:

```
        master
        |   foo
        |   |
        v   v         bar
A---B---C---D         |
         \            v
          \---E---F---G
```

so *I* think I need to do:

```
git checkout bar
git rebase master
```

but Git thinks otherwise:

```
Current branch bar is up-to-date.
```

and leaves everything as it is.

What do I need to run to make Git do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `git rebase` that you are doing, takes all of the commits on the branch `bar` which are not already on `master` and writes them onto `master`. This is commits `D` through `F`, which isn't what you want because it doesn't skip commit `D`. One solution is to use the `--onto` flag:

```
git checkout bar
git rebase --onto master foo
```

This version of rebase will take all of the commits on the branch `bar` but not on branch `foo` and rewrite them onto `master`. This will result in exactly the history for `bar` that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Commit `D` is included on the branch `bar`.  One option is to do an [interactive rebase](https://billtheconqueror.com/2018/07/24/commit-early-commit-often-the-interactive-rebase-delete/) and delete commit `D` from branch `bar`.

1. `git checkout bar`
2. `git rebase -i master`
3. In text editor delete line of commit `D`
4. Save and close

As long as you have a tag or branch on commit `D` (or that includes commit `D`) (for example `foo`) you should not lose it.  Also remember that if the commits after `D` depend on changes in `D` you will get conflicts.