# Git pull not retrieving commits from origin

Tags: git

So currently, there are 4 commits(the most recent 4) in origin/master that are not in my remote repository or my local repository.

When I use git pull, it tells me that I'm already up to date, but using git log clearly shows that I don't have the 4 newest commits that origin/master has. I can push changes to my remote no problem, so I'm fairly certain that the problem isn't between the remote and the local repo.

I have tried both

```
git pull origin master
```

as well as

```
git pull
```

The structure is very simple it is just

```
Origin/Master-->Remote-->Working directory
```

Comment: The way that you are using the terms origin/master, remote, etc are confusing.  It would be helpful to include a representative tree with branch/commit names (even if they are not the real names that you have).  See this for one example of a tree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192249/git-rebase-not-updating-branch/52192291

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: `origin` is the local name of the remote repository used to create the current repository. How many remote repositories do you use?

Comment: fork    http://[IP-Address]/[username]/CatalogueGUI (fetch)
fork    http://[IP-Address]/[username]/CatalogueGUI (push)
origin  http://[IP-Address]/[username]/CatalogueGUI (fetch)
origin  disable (push)

Comment: @axiac I must be using the wrong nomenclature here. What I'm referring to as origin master is the central repo containing the production code, and what i'm referring to as remote is my personal fork of that repo.

Comment: It sounds like you need to update your forked repository before you `pull` in your local.  This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It turns out what the problem was that when I set up the local repo, I had accidentally cloned my fork of the production repo and not the production repo itself, which is why I was able to push my local commits, but not pull new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your local branch, and clone the project again, seems like your local git is not tracking the repo correctly

Comment: This actually ended up working because the repo had been incorrectly cloned in the first place.